# How to build a simple search form with rails and advance search form with ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

Everyone, I am to redirected my search result to an advanced search form with more filters using the ransack gem. when i click the search buttom, it goes to my 'search_path' but displays no result 
My console log prints this sql query

```
  SELECT  "listings".* FROM "listings" WHERE ( status <> NULL AND town = 'milan') LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2  [["LIMIT", 15], ["OFFSET", 0]]
```

I don't understand why status <> NULL. I was expecting status[:pending]

But the advanced search works very fine . My simple form in on my index page

### here is my search controller

```
def search
@param_s =  params[:search]
if @param_s && @param_s != ""
    @listing_search = Listing.includes(:photos).where(" status <> ? AND town = ?",Listing.statuses[:pendeng], @param_s).page( params[:page]).per(4)
  else
    @listing_search = Listing.includes(:photos).pending.page( params[:page]).per(20)
end

@search = @listing_search.ransack(params[:q])
@listing = @search.result.page( params[:page]).per(15)
@arrlisting = @listing.to_a
end
```

### I have this generic form in my index page

```
<%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
<%end%>
```

#### and this is my advanced search form

```
<%= search_form_for @search, url: search_path,remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :home_type_cont,[["Apartment","apartment"],["Flat","flat"],["Hostel","hostel"],["Room","room"],["Business","business"]],{:include_blank => 'Select....'} %>
 <%= f.select :bed_room_gteq,[["1",1],["2",2],["3",3],["4 +",4]]%>
  ----more-- filters
<%end%>
```

### Listing model

```
class Listing < ApplicationRecord
enum status: [:pending, :rejected, :approved ]

belongs_to :user
has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy
validates :listing_name, presence: true
validates :town, presence: true
validates :home_type, presence: true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo `Listing.statuses[:pendeng]`, it should be `Listing.statuses[:pending]`, so this is why it is returning `nil` instead of the correct value.

Also it looks like you already have a scope for `pending`:

```
Listing.includes(:photos).pending.where(town: params[:search])
```

Comment: Thanks . I corrected the typo error but nothing changed, I still have the null value and no result display

Comment: Pls, can you post your Listing model, also have you tried using the `pending` scope?

Comment: i added the Listing model